# Using DataBinding on custom views

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to create custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateTint="#FFFFFF" />

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

And Java:

```
public class ImageSlideshowView extends FrameLayout {
    private ViewImageSlideshowBinding binding;

    public ImageSlideshowView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
    }

    public ImageSlideshowView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init(context);
    }

    public ImageSlideshowView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr, @StyleRes int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        init(context);
    }

    private void init(@NonNull Context context) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        binding = ViewImageSlideshowBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, this, true);
    }
}
```

It works, but not correct.

If I use `merge` tag instead of FrameLayout without data binding, I'll get the following layout (I finally want to get **this** layout):

> -- FrameLayout
>
> --- ProgressBar

But I can not use `merge` with data binding, so with XML above I'm getting the following layout:

> -- FrameLayout
>
> --- FrameLayout
>
> ---- ProgressBar

As you can see, there is one more FrameLayout created. How to avoid it?

Comment: Why can't you use a merge layout with data binding?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Android Studio says that merge is not allowed within <layout> tags.

Comment: Works for me. I don't see any error or warning (2.4 preview). Data Binding doesn't support includes as the root of merge tags, but it is otherwise fine.

Comment: @GeorgeMount Hm, that's strange, I'm using the latest 2.4 canary and Android Studio says that <merge>  is not allowed. So, in fact, merge can be root tag withing layout tag?

Comment: There are restrictions, but yes. My Android Studio isn't giving me an error or warning. Are you seeing a compilation error or just a squiggly underline?

Comment: Maybe post the layout which is not working?

Comment: Can you try by placing last parameter false, binding = ViewImageSlideshowBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, this, false);

Comment: @GeorgeMount thanks, I've tried — it builds and works correctly (but still shows warning: https://i.imgur.com/euajDkC.png). I thinks it's just a lint bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view is a `FrameLayout`. And that layout contains a `FrameLayout` and a `ProgressBar`.

Try instead a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.yourcompany.yourapp.ImageSlideshowView
        android:id="@+id/container_fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminateTint="#FFFFFF" />

    </com.yourcompany.yourapp.ImageSlideshowView>

</layout>
```

Then when you include your custom view in another view you can just refer to it by its type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>


    </data>

    <com.yourcompany.yourapp.ParentView
        android:id="@+id/parent_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.yourcompany.yourapp.ImageSlideshowView
            android:id="@+id/slideshow_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.yourcompany.yourapp.ParentView>
</layout>
```